# webView loading link causes memory warning?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

So on the screen i have a webview that loads xbox.com friends page.  To make the app work you have to press a link on the screen which loads 25 players that you recently played with and when i push this link i get a memory warning.  And eventually the app will crash after the the link has been presses multiple times.  Is there anything i can do to stop it from crashing?  I have tried setting the webView to nil after i get the recent player list but that did not seem to help.  Anybody know what is wrong if i am doing something wrong or it is a bug with webView?

Answer (score 0):

It is nearly impossible to determine exactly what might be causing the crash with out seeing the project source code and running it through Instruments to determine the source of the memory consumption. I would highly recommend that you profile the application. Please see this article on [Locating Memory Issues in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp/MemoryManagementforYouriOSApp.html)